# Most used word in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I find the most used word in a string, without importing anything?

```
>>> x = "In the sky, I fly fly away"
>>> common(x) 
'fly'
```

And this is my code so far, but I'm having problems.

```
def common(x):
    dict = {}
    for i in x:
        try:
            dict[i] += 1
        except KeyError:
            dict[i] = 1
    return (sorted(dict.items(), key = lambda k: k[1], reverse = True)[:1])
```

Comment: **What** problems are you having?

Answer (score 2):

Return the first key instead (in reverse sorted order):

```
return sorted(dict, key=dict.get, reverse=True)[0]
```

Try to avoid naming your variables `dict`; this masks the built-in type and serves only to confuse. Use `count` instead, for example. Here is a simpler version:

```
def common(f):
    count = {}
    max = None
    for i in f:
        count[i] = count.get(i, 0) + 1
        if count[i] > count.get(max, 0):
            max = i
    return max
```

Note that this version does away with sorting altogether. Instead, we update `max` as we go along with counting.

You also need to remember to split your sentence into words first:

```
>>> common(x.split())
'fly'
```

Comment: I received this error:                                                  count = count.get(i, 0) + 1
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @BeginnersLuck: I corrected an error early on; try again now. :-)

Comment: Another way to do this would be to `return max(count, key=count.get)`. That avoids the sort and the code to keep a running max. It also raises a `ValueError` if the input is empty, which may or may not be a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you just create a dictionary of word counts, reverse sort and render the first element in the list.
Code below is Python 3.

**Note:**  *You will need to tweak the word parsing logic to suit your fancy (e.g. ignore punctuation, etc.).*

**Code solution using no imports**

```
def get_word_counts(words):
    word_list = words.split()
    word_counts = {}
    for word in word_list:
        if word in word_counts.keys():
            word_counts[word] +=1
        else:
            word_counts[word] = 1

    return word_counts.items()

print(sorted(get_word_counts( "In the sky, I fly fly away"), 
      key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))
print("Most frequent word in phrase is: ", 
       list(sorted(get_word_counts( "In the sky, I fly fly away"), 
                   key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))[0][0])
```

I'm not really sure why you'd want to do it without using imports, since the standard library has a more succinct way to get the same end result.

**Code that uses imports (much shorter)**

```
print (sorted(Counter("In the sky, I fly fly away".split()).items(),
       key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
print("Most frequent word in phrase is: ",
       sorted(Counter("In the sky, I fly fly away".split()).items(),
       key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[0][0])
```

Comment: `Counter('In the sky, I fly fly away'.split()).most_common()[0][0]`

Comment: Would the code solution using no imports work for several most words used? Example: "hey you, you are very very pretty" --in this case, both 'you' and 'very' are used twice. @Allan